# Update Text File Using Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to be able to update a text file whenever I upload an image to the s3 bucket. This text file will contain on each line the results of Amazon Rekognition. However, the code I've written isn't working properly

```
bucket_name = "update-my-text-file"
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

def handle_image(key):
    response = rekognition.detect_labels(
        Image={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucket_name,
                'Name': key
            }
        }
    )
    return response


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    file_name = 'results.txt'
    object = s3.Object(bucket_name, 'tmp/results.txt')

    cli = boto3.client('s3')
    response = cli.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='tmp/results.txt')
    data = response['Body'].read()
    print('the data is ' + data)

    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
    response = handle_image(key)
    print('the response is: ' + response)

    object.put(Body=data + '/n' + response)
```

Comment: That's too vague. What happens, exactly, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to download the file like this:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

Then you can read/write the local file however you wish. Then, upload again with:

```
s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```